# React. Несколько событий на одну кнопку

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть список, который отрисовывает айтемы (они же карточки товара).
У каждой карточки, есть набор кнопок, при нажатии на которые, под выбранной карточкой отрисовывается данные. Например, одна кнопка показывает отзывы, другая список доступных товаров, третью - ещё там что-то.
Как сейчас работают эти кнопки:

1. Жму на карточке 1, кнопку "показать товары". Поднимаю id карточки, на которой произошло нажатие наверх, в айтемЛист, записываю там id в стейт и отправляю обратно в карточку, отправляю true в карточку товара и товары показываются;
2. Жму на карточке 2, кнопку "показать товары". Дальше всё, что описал выше... Товары показываются и скрываются уже открытые под карточкой 1. В общем обычный аккордеон.
   С этим я справился.
   Но допустим, я хотел бы скрывать данные при повторном нажатии на кнопку "показать товары" в **той же** карточке товара.

Сейчас это не работает, и проблема в том, что я не могу понять, как на кнопку "показать товары", повесить обработку более одного события? Подскажите, как это решается в реакте? Нужно обрабатывать на ItemList или на Item или может какой-то хитрый HOC пишется в такой ситуации?
Воспроизводимый пример тут https://codesandbox.io/s/toggledata-pxhdu?file=/src/components/Goods.js:0-215

спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В методе `showGoods` необходимо проверять `id`. Если `id` равен активному `activeItemId` из `state` (второе нажатие) то сбрасываем `activeItemId` в `null`:

```
showGoods(id) {
    this.setState({
      activeItemId: this.state.activeItemId === id ? null : id
    });
}
```

Comment: Класс, спасибо!